# First eigenvalue of Schrödinger operator is simple

Tags: schrodinger-operators

I once read that the first eigenvalue of a Schrödinger operator always is simple, together with an easy proof of it. But I cannot remember where. Does anybody know a reference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Say that $V$ be bounded by below. Up to the addition of a large enough constant, you may assume that $V\ge0$. Then argue as follow.

The operator $L=-\Delta+V$ (where $V(x)$ is the potential) satisfies the maximum principle: if $f\ge0$ and $f\not\equiv0$, then the solution $u$ of $-\Delta u+Vu=f$ exists, is unique and satisfies $u>0$. Then apply the Krein--Rutman Theorem to $L^{-1}$ ; this is the infinite-dimensional version of Perron-Frobenius Theorem, the latter applying to positive matrices. You find that the spectral radius is an eigenvalue, a simple one, associated with a positive eigenfunction.

Comment: Excuse me, for the maximum principle, do we assume $V\geq 0$?

Comment: @user38600. Add a constant to $V$, and do the same argument.

Answer (score 1):

Barry Simon's book, "[Functional Integration and Quantum Physics](http://books.google.it/books?id=6Wcaa2ddplEC&printsec=frontcover&hl=it&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)", should fit the bill.